# How to calculate memory size in Ehcache?

Tags: memory, ehcache, memorycache, ehcache-2

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.UnsafeSizeOf;

public class EhCacheTest {

    private List<Double> testList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EhCacheTest test = new EhCacheTest();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            test.addItem(1.0);
            System.out.println(new UnsafeSizeOf().sizeOf(test));
        }
    }

    public void addItem(double a) {
        testList.add(a);
    }
}
```

I used UnsafeSizeOf to calculate the size of Object 'test'.
Nomatter how many doubles I add into the list, the size of 'test' is always 16 bytes.

Because of this, the maxBytesLocalHeap paramater is useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code snippet, this is totally expected.

See [the javadoc](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.4/net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/SizeOf.html#sizeOf(java.lang.Object)) of the method `SizeOf.sizeOf`, it clearly states that it sizes the instance *without* navigating the object graph.

What you want to use is `SizeOf.deepSizeOf` which will navigate the object graph.

However this test is flawed, cause you risk comparing that specific `SizeOf` implementation against another one, as Ehcache uses multiple implementations, depending on what's available in a specific environment.

If you really want to confirm the byte sizing on heap works, you are better off filling a cache, finding out the size it reports through statistics and then do a heap dump to see how much memory is effectively used.